# PHP fwrite() duplicates and replaced rows obtained through fgets()

Tags: php, fwrite, fgets

I am trying to write a small php function which reads up every 10th line, detects if there is a semi-colon and replace it with a commit statement `; => into ; commit;`.

I'm using fgets because the file could potentially be very large like 1GB, while I do not want to save it into another new file, which will use up additional spaces.

my function is

$targetFile = fopen($file,'r+');

```
// if can open
if ($targetFile){

  $count ='';
  // loop every line
  while (($lines = fgets($targetFile)) !== false){

    $count++;

    // for line of no.10
    if( $count == '10' ){

      //if matches a semi-colon
      if( preg_match('/;/',$lines) == true ){

        // replace semi-colon with commit statement
        $insertLine = preg_replace('/;/','; commit;', $lines);

        echo file_get_contents('./1.sql'); // to debug

        fwrite($targetFile, $insertLine); // <= problem arises

        echo file_get_contents('./1.sql'); // to debug

        //reset counter
        $count = '0';
      }else{
        //lower the count to check next line
        --$count;
      }
    }
  }
}else{
  system("echo file $targetFile cannot be opened\n");
}

fclose($targetFile);
```

The target file **before** execution

```
LINE1;
LINE2;
LINE3;
LINE4;
LINE5;
LINE6;
LINE7;
LINE8;
LINE9;
LINE10;
LINE11;
LINE12;
LINE13;
```

**After** execution:

```
LINE1;
LINE2;
LINE3;
LINE4;
LINE5;
LINE6;
LINE7;
LINE8;
LINE9;
LINE10;
LINE10; commit;
LINE13;
```

*The question is why would fwrite() replace the 11th line and removed the 12th line*

Comment: "I do not want to save it into another new file" - tough, you have to. I/O is not line based. You can't replace a line, only bytes. Meaning, you can replace a line if and only if the new line is the exact same line length - if the new line is longer (or shorter), you must write a new file.

Comment: understood. So this is not a sound solution. What we can do about appending a word or a line for every _n-th_ line? Assuming space is expensive and saving into a new file is not the best option we would consider?

Comment: Space is almost always the cheapest resource you have, but ok. What you can do is keep a rolling buffer of excess data. This buffer will grow with every additional byte you add to the file, so the method is only useful if you know the total additions add up to less RAM than you want to use. Ideally, use record based storage instead, such as SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while you are iterating through the file with `while (($lines = fgets($targetFile)) !== false)` the file pointer is going forward. So when you reach the 10th line you re file pointer is already pointing to the next one, the 11th, so you overwrite the 11th line.

So this is what i would do:

```
$filename = "input.txt";
$in = fopen($filename,'r+');
if($in)
{
  $count = 0;
  $last = 0;

  // loop every line
  while (($lines = fgets($in)) !== false)
  {
    $count++;
    if( $count % 10 == 0 && preg_match('/;/',$lines) )
    {
      $content = file_get_contents($filename, FALSE, null, ftell($in));

      $insertLine = preg_replace('/;/',"; commit;", $lines);

      // go back to the end of the last line
      fseek($in, $last, SEEK_SET);
      fwrite($in, $insertLine);

      // insert the content from the next line to the end, otherwise it will modified. You see this if you remove this line 
      fwrite($in, $content);
    }
    else
    {
      //Save the position where ends the last line
      $last = ftell($in);
    }
  }
}
else
{
  echo "Input file cannot be opened\n";
}

fclose($in);
```

You could find a more efficient way to get the content of the file `$content = file_get_contents($filename, FALSE, null, ftell($in));` or maybe use a temp file, based on your needs.

Comment: That would be murder for a 1 GB file. The only solution is to write a new temporary file.

Comment: Yeah you re right, the best way is a temporary file. I didn t investigate further because the question was "why would fwrite() replace the 11th line and removed the 12th line"